# AZTEC validateProof and validateProofByHash sender / signer addresses

Tags: solidity, javascript, zero-knowledge

The AZTEC Crypto Engine lets you validate proofs and cache them for future re-use, since they are fairly expensive (around 800,000 gas for a 4-note join-split proof before Istanbul, and now about 200,000 gas). This question refers to aztec.js 0.9.1.

The proofs contain a `signer`, the address of the owner of the notes to operate on, and a `sender` or `validator`, the address of the (possibly a contract) sender of the proofs to ACE.

When you validate the proofs and cache them, you provide one address, which is called the sender

https://github.com/AztecProtocol/AZTEC/blob/2e30619dd39182982a0d6cce57de2cd015c1e8d0/packages/protocol/contracts/ACE/ACE.sol#L179

This is a mutator method and I would expect an EVM revert if it fails.

When you want to read from the cache, you also provide an address called `sender`, which I expect to be the same as `sender` used in the call above to write to the cache, and the `proofHash`:

https://github.com/AztecProtocol/AZTEC/blob/2e30619dd39182982a0d6cce57de2cd015c1e8d0/packages/protocol/contracts/ACE/ACE.sol#L287

My question is: do the calls to either or both of `ace.validateProof` and `ace.validateProofByHash` have to come from the same address as the `sender` address parameter?

To test this, I first make a call from Javascript that relays a call to `ace.validateProof` via a contract called `TradeValidator`

```
      const sellerValidation = await result.minedTx(
        result.validator.validateAndGetFirstProofOutput,
        [result.seller.jsProofData, result.validator.address] )
```

The Solidity code of the method `validateAndGetFirstProofOutput` is

```
   function validateAndGetFirstProofOutput(
        bytes memory _proofData,
        address _proofSender
    ) public returns (bytes memory, bytes32) {
        bytes memory formattedProofOutput = ace.validateProof(JOIN_SPLIT_PROOF, _proofSender, _proofData).get(0);
        lastProofOutput = formattedProofOutput;
        lastProofHash = keccak256(formattedProofOutput);
        return (lastProofOutput, lastProofHash);
    }
```

I've verified that the `proofHash` is what I expect from Javascript, and then I also tried to verify that this proof is cached by calling from Javascript

```
      const validateResult2 = await result.ace.validateProofByHash(
        JOIN_SPLIT_PROOF, result.seller.jsProofHash, result.validator.address,
      )
      assert( Boolean(validateResult2['0']),
        'seller proof hash is not associated with transferer/sender, when sent from Javascript user'
      )
```

My expectation is that `ace.validateProofByHash` would succeed if `proofHash` matches `JOIN_SPLIT_PROOF` type and `sender` address, when called from anywhere, whether it's a Solidity contract, a Node command-line user, or webpacked JS code in a browser. However, this second call is currently failing.

Two ways I can test this:

1. Does `ace.validateProof` revert if the `sender` parameter is incorrect, or if it comes from a different sender?
2. Can I make a Solidity method in the validator contract that also calls `ace.validateProofByHash`, but coming from the same `sender` address as the parameter?

Comment: The answer to #1 above is that submitting an incorrect proof will indeed cause an EVM revert, and therefore not cost gas. (Possibly DoS attack vector).

https://gist.github.com/cryptogoth/285d2e55f3818fad54072ca9f9f18f9a

Comment: Also yes to #2, such a call works.
It turns out that the answer to this question is:
* The address to a proof is the sender / validator, not the signer.
* The call to *both* `validateProof` and `validateProofByHash` must come from the sender (whether it's a user address called from Javascript, or a Solidity contract)

Answer (score 0):

The address needed for a proof is the sender / validator, not the signer / owner. The call to both validateProof and validateProofByHash must come from the same sender (whether it's a user address called from Javascript, or a Solidity contract).

For example, if `senderAddress` is a contract called `TradeValidator`, then in order to call ACE you need methods

```
    function validateProof(
        uint24 _proofType,
        address _sender,
        bytes memory _proofData
    ) public returns (bytes memory) {
        require(_sender == address(this), 'transferer address mismatch');
        return ace.validateProof(_proofType, _sender, _proofData);
    }

    // Same signature as ACE.validateProofByHash to allow swapping one for the other
    function validateProofByHash(
        uint24 _proofType,
        bytes32 _proofHash,
        address _sender
    ) public view returns (bool) {
        require(_sender == address(this), 'transferer address mismatch');
        return ace.validateProofByHash(_proofType, _proofHash, _sender);
    }
```

and then you may call both methods (`validateProof` first and `validateProofByHash` afterwards) from Javascript, or from Solidity.

The actual caller doesn't need to match the sender address for `validateProof{,ByHash}` to succeed, so in Solidity, your final call to `validateProofByHash` should use or `address(this)`, in `ZkAsset*` in your `confidential*` methods, to require that only valid signed proofs previously validated can have ownership transferred.

```
    function confidentialTrade(
        bytes memory _proofOutputs,
        bytes memory _signatures,
        bytes memory _proofData
    ) public {

        bytes memory formattedProofOutput = ParamUtils.sliceBytes(_proofOutput, 32, _proofOutput.length);

        bytes32 proofHash = keccak256(formattedProofOutput);
        require( ace.validateProofByHash(
            JOIN_SPLIT_PROOF, proofHash, address(this)
            ), "proof output is invalid" );

        bytes memory proofOutput = TradeUtils.getFirstProofOutput(_proofOutputs);

        (,
        ,
        ,
        int256 publicValue) = proofOutput.extractProofOutput();

        (
            ,
            uint256 scalingFactor,
            uint256 totalSupply,
            ,
            ,
            ,
        ) = ace.getRegistry(address(this));
        if (publicValue > 0) {
            if (totalSupply < uint256(publicValue)) {
                uint256 supplementValue = uint256(publicValue).sub(totalSupply);
                ERC20Mintable(address(linkedToken)).mint(address(this), supplementValue.mul(scalingFactor));
                ERC20Mintable(address(linkedToken)).approve(address(ace), supplementValue.mul(scalingFactor));

                ace.supplementTokens(supplementValue);
            }
        }
        // It seems like there should be a confidentialBurn here too

        confidentialTransferInternal(_proofOutputs, _signatures, _proofData);
    }
```